# Split .csv by comma but skip one comma (Powershell)

Tags: powershell, csv, split, delimiter

I am novice in Powershell and still haven't found a solution to my issue on stackoverflow but I still think PS is the best tool for this purpose.

I have a .csv file and it has to be splitted into separate columns by comma, but the first comma has to be skipped. It looks like this:

[image]

The goals is to have 3 columns: "Name, Surname (Link Personal)", "SSO", and "Access"

[image]

If I am not mistaken, the way to split it into every single comma would be:

```
import-csv \\file.csv | export-csv -Delimiter "," -path \\updated_file.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a calculated property to concatenate the two first columns into one

```
Import-Csv -Path \\file.csv | 
    Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'Name, Surname (Link Personal)'; Expression= {"$($_.Name), $($_.'Surname (Link Personal)')"}}, SSO, Access |
        Export-Csv -Path \\updated_file.csv -Delimiter ','
```

And BTW: When you post sample data you should post them as text formatted as code. So people willing to help you can copy and play around with them. ;-)

Comment: Interestingly, the correct format gets displayed in the powershell console. However, the newly generated .csv file is empty (compared to the original one). Do you eventually have any idea why this happens?

Comment: not without seeing your actual code ... ;-)

Comment: I found the issue. It was just a simple " | " symbol I forgot. Such a silly mistake. But it works now ;)